# What kind of data encoding is this?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, encoding

I am trying to understand what kind of encoding is this:

SA÷1¬~ZA÷ARABIA SAUDITA: Premier League¬ZEE÷tUxUbLR2¬ZB÷165¬ZY÷Arabia Saudita¬ZC÷2N9fqQb5¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷KMnRw3da¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷165_tUxUbLR2¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/calcio/arabia-saudita/premier-league/¬ZX÷00Arabia Saudi014audita0000000000169000Premier Leag014League000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷Arabia Saudita¬~AA÷j9D0dEjl¬AD÷1511448300¬ADE÷1511448300¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Al Feiha¬RW÷0¬AX÷0¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷AL¬AE÷Al Feiha¬JA÷tE4MVe35¬WU÷al-feiha¬WN÷SHA¬AF÷Al Shabab¬JB÷zy4QUFIB¬WV÷al-shabab¬AN÷y¬MW÷419¬~AA÷YX25eY5f¬AD÷1511448600¬ADE÷1511448600¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Al-Raed¬RW÷0¬AX÷0¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WN÷OHU¬AF÷Ohud¬JB÷W2cZSgmO¬WV÷ohud¬WM÷RAE¬AE÷Al-Raed¬JA÷lv8UTZXH¬WU÷al-raed¬AN÷y¬MW÷419¬~AA÷CO19fhL0¬AD÷1511455200¬ADE÷1511455200¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Al Nasr Riyadh¬RW÷0¬AX÷0¬BX÷-1¬WQ÷¬WM÷NAS¬AE÷Al Nasr Riyadh¬JA÷AgdwSD2U¬WU÷al-nasr-riyadh¬WN÷ITT¬AF÷Al-Ittihad FC¬JB÷MRxqmcYu¬WV÷al-ittihad¬AN÷y¬MW÷419¬~ZA÷ARGENTINA: Superliga¬ZEE÷naYhNOaA¬ZB÷22¬ZY÷Argentina¬ZC÷67b39Wvk¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷hhYlbPDp¬ZF÷
[...]

This is the response of an XHR request that is decoded by a javascript application. It may be compressed data.

Comment: was was the original encoding of your request? The encoding sent as a response might appear different depending on which encoding you try to visualize it (because bytes are understood differently)

Comment: @Kaddath I thought the same thing but i couldn't find the right encoding. Do you have any idea?